# selenium webdriver for java API: findElement produces different results

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium webdriver for java to crawl this page:

https://www.immowelt.at/liste/wien/wohnungen/mieten?sort=relevanz

In my code the method

`WebElement.findElement(...)`

produces different results, as follows:

1.) My Source Code:

```
package at.home.digest.services;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import at.home.digest.model.HomeToDeal;

public class ImmoweltBot {

    public static final String URL = "https://www.immowelt.at/";
    public static final String queryURL = URL + "/liste/wien/wohnungen/mieten?sort=relevanz";


    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Temp\\chromedriver.exe");

        String URLPage = StringUtils.EMPTY;
        int page = 1;
        int totalNumberOfEntities = 6000;
        int numberOfEntitiesFound = 0;

        List<WebElement> elemnts = new ArrayList<>();

        WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();

        outer:
        while (numberOfEntitiesFound < totalNumberOfEntities){

        webDriver.get(queryURL + URLPage);


        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 5);
        By searchResults = By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'clear relative js-listitem')]");

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)webDriver;
        webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)");

        final int totalNumberOfKeyDowns = 190;
        int keyDownTries = 0;
        while ((++keyDownTries < totalNumberOfKeyDowns)) {
            elemnts = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(searchResults));
            webDriver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);

        }

        WebElement elem = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'ellipsis margin_none')]"));
        totalNumberOfEntities = Utils.parseNumber(elem.getText()).intValue();

        for (int i = 0; i < elemnts.size(); i++) {
            WebElement divListItemClear = elemnts.get(i);
            HomeToDeal homeToRent = new HomeToDeal();
            String exposeURL = divListItemClear.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getAttribute("href");
            homeToRent.setURL(exposeURL);

            WebElement listContentClear = divListItemClear.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'listcontent clear')]"));
            WebElement h2Elem = listContentClear.findElement(By.tagName("h2"));
            String text = h2Elem.getText();
            homeToRent.setDescription(text);

            System.out.println(homeToRent);
        }

        URLPage = "&cp="+ (++page);
        numberOfEntitiesFound+=elemnts.size();
     }
    }

}
```

My problem is that the line

```
String exposeURL = divListItemClear.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getAttribute("href");
```

works as expected and gives me the subsequent URL of the elemement (for each new itteration in the cycle), however the lines

```
WebElement listContentClear = divListItemClear.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'listcontent clear')]"));
        WebElement h2Elem = listContentClear.findElement(By.tagName("h2"));
        String text = h2Elem.getText();
```

give me EACH TIME ONE AND THE SAME value of the HTML elment h2- and this is always the value of the first element found.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve fallen victim to a classic mistake that a lot of people make when using XPath with Selenium. WebDriver implementations follow the XPath specification for locating elements, which means the `//` locator *always* refers to the top of the document. This is even so if you’re using `findElement` from a `WebElement` instance. In the code you referenced that gives the error,  what you want is the following:

```
WebElement listContentClear = divListItemClear.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(@class, 'listcontent clear')]"));
WebElement h2Elem = listContentClear.findElement(By.tagName("h2"));
String text = h2Elem.getText();
```

Note the `.` at beginning of the locator, indicating the current node as the context node. Since you’re largely finding elements based on values in the elements’ CSS class,  this is one case where using CSS selectors instead of XPath would have avoided the issue.

As an aside, I’d consider these locators somewhat fragile, as the class attribute does not guarantee ordering of the class values. In other words, as far as the browser is concerned, `<div class="listcontent clear">` is semantically equivalent to `<div class="clear listcontent">`. If the browser were to render the elements as the latter rather than the former, the CSS selector `div.listcontent.clear` would find both renderings, while the XPath you’re using would not.